# Java generics vs C++ templates

Tags: java, c++, templates

I know Java generics and C++ templates are different, but how do I write the following generic equivalent in C++?

```
void myalgo (List<? extends T> myList)
{
    //logic
}
```

This should take any container containing `T` or subclass of `T`. How can I do a similar thing in C++?

Comment: You wouldn't generally bother constraining containers in C++. You'd just have `template <typename T> void myalgo(T & myList)`. If you really have to, you can stick a static assertion into the function template body.

Comment: If your algorithm works on a range of values, the preferable way to write the template is to use iterators, not specific containers as the template type.

Comment: Your container will be a container of smart pointers to the base class. Your function will also take a reference to the container, rather than by value. C++ is not Java, and works fundamentally differently.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That parameter should be: std::vector<T> myList.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: really? Why not `std::vector<T, A>`? Or `std::deque<T>`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sure - anything but what you initially used.

Answer (score -1):

There's no equivalent for the constraint part, but generally the following will suffice:

```
#include <vector>

public:
template<typename T>
void myalgo(std::vector<T> myList)
{
    //logic
}
```